# error: 'NSUnarchiver' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have just tried using the NSArchiver but for some reason I am getting this error.

I have downloaded a sample project and get the same error too.

Could it be something wrong with my installation?!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using NSKeyedUnarchiver?